# How to apply box-shadow around the box including arrow tip?

Tags: css

I am trying to create a tooltip with shadow-box. all works fine. But I am not able to get the shadow to tool tip part( arrow part ) how to get that?

here is my code :

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px dashed green;
  height: 200px;
}

.toolTip {
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}

.tipPoint {
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid white;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="toolTip">
    <span class="tipPoint"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't using `box-shadow`..your box is a rectangle...you might manage something with a `drop-shadow ` but you will need to think of an alternative method if you are using borders to make your shape.

Comment: here is cool codepen for you which exactly focused the same problem: https://codepen.io/ryanmcnz/pen/JDLhu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another solution is to use the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter) property set to [`drop-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter#drop-shadow()_2) 
Also you'll need to use the [`:after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/::after) pseudo selector for the arrow.

Vendor prefixes are available, but unfortunately the feature is not supported by IE. Check for [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter#Browser_compatibility).

```css
.toolTip {
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5));
}

.toolTip:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="toolTip">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

## Tweaking the `box-shadow` property

The property [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) is in fact applied to your element `.tipPoint` but the shadow is on the bottom of the box. You can easily tweak it's value by changing the shadow's direction on `.tipPoint`: for example the following looks good:

```
box-shadow: 1px 0px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
```

For more details here's how the property works:

```
box shadow: <offset-x> <offset-y> <blur-radius> <spread-radius> <color>
```

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px dashed green;
  height: 200px;
}

.toolTip {
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}

.tipPoint {
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid white;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="toolTip">
    <span class="tipPoint"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Tip:** Chrome has a nice shadow editor that you can use to set your values:
[image]

---

## Creating an arrow with shadow

If you really want to get it right, there's a way you can make an arrow with shadow. Instead of having a child div `tipPoint` under `.toolTip` you can use the [`:after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/::after) pseudo-selector. Will create a cube and rotate it 45deg with [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transform):

```css
.tipPoint {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 16px 10px -17px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.tipPoint:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #999;
  transform: rotate(45deg); /* Prefixes... */
  top: 75px;
  left: 25px;
  box-shadow: -1px -1px 10px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="tipPoint"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a box-shadow on the main element combined with pseudo elements that overlay each other. This method will result in a seamless drop shadow around the tooltip while using only one element.

See codepen for demo: https://codepen.io/JKudla/pen/GvWYEx

```
.Tooltip {
  width: 15em;
  height: 10em;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  position: relative;
}
.Tooltip:after,
.Tooltip:before {
  content: '';
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  height: 1.5em;
}
.Tooltip:before {
  width: 1.5em;
  right: 1.5em;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: -0.75em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  z-index: 0;
}
.Tooltip:after {
  width: 3em;
  top: 0;
  right: 0.75em;
  z-index: 1;
}
```